# Mysql Workbench: any way to force lines for relationships to be straight?

Tags: mysql-workbench

As you know, when a relationship between two tables on a schema diagram is created, a line between them is drawn. Do you know any way to force those lines to be straight?

v. 5.2.34

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunatelly the only way to do that is to edit the table position manually: select the table, and in the Properties Editor adjust the Top/Left properties until you reach the alignment>

[image]

Comment: This is painful, but upvote for the answer ;) They should take inspiration from Omni Graffle and let you snap to straight lines while holding the control key / apple key etc down.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there is an option called "Align objects to grid".

Comment: Seems "align to grid" doesn't get the tables to have straight lines between them, or maybe I'm missing something still?

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing the zoom to 200% allows you to tweak the lines and get them straight most of the time.